# Azure Table InsertOrReplace return item before updated

Tags: azure-table-storage

I have an Azure table that contains a list of objects all with common columns.

I would like to upsert records, and if a an entity was replaced I will raise an event for the properties that were changed.

In order to this I would need to get the record before the upsert and compare it with my object, but in an atomic operation (read prior, upsert, compare any difference).

Is there a method that would do this or will I need to use a transaction scope?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question. An upset operation will either create an entity or replace an existing entity using the data you are providing. In any case, the upserted entity will be the same as the data you are providing if the operation is successful.

Comment: Yes apologies Gaurav, not enough coffee. have edited my question

Comment: `Is there a method that would do this or will I need to use a transaction scope?` - AFAIK, no such method exists. Even transaction scope ([Entity Group Transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/performing-entity-group-transactions)) cannot be used in this scenario. You will need to handle this on your own.